# Wifi issues with iTerm2 as frontmost application on external monitor

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, multiple-monitors, iterm2, macbook-pro-retina

I have reproduced this many times yesterday and today, and I am confident that I'm not just looking for patterns where there are none.

I have a retina Macbook Pro (OSX 10.8) connected to a Dell monitor by a DVI-HDMI cable. I'm connected to a wireless N router with good signal. When the monitor is on and iTerm2 is the frontmost application on the external monitor (with any colorscheme), and only when all of these things are the case, I can't use the wifi (either for remote connections or local connections), although the signal is still good (i.e. I have full bars on the wifi icon in the toolbar). I have tried every conceivable window setup, and this is the only time wifi drops.

This is seriously strange. I know it's easy to 'fix' (just don't have this window setup), but I want to know what's going on. If you can assume that I'm not making this up (which I'm not) and I've correctly described the symptoms, I'd love to know if you either have any idea why this is, or are able to reproduce it.

Comment: Welcome to Super User, Toby. Have you also considered raising a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/list) with iTerm2?

Comment: I'm just not sure it's an iTerm2 bug. I'd like to know if anybody else could replicate it, and I thought posting it here would get the widest audience.

Comment: Yeah, it's a strange issue indeed, and of course there's no problem with keeping your question here.